Why does USB-C port work with DisplayPort but not with USB flash drive?
The model was Lenovo Legion Pro 7 Gen 8 (16″ AMD) Gaming Laptop with latest Windows 11. (Nvidia 4080)
The USB-C port at rear and left side somehow stopped recognize the USB flash drive or any other USB flash drive device. I tried to use the phone and it showed it's not charging either. It still worked with video output at 2K resolution.
I tried to install the AMD driver, Nvidia driver, and reinstalled the Windows, but it didn't help. I tired to delete the usb controller and reinstalled it, but it also didn't help. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with Thunderbolt 4 but the website said Windows 11 does not need it, though it's technically USB 3.2.

The Universal Serial Bus devices had an "APP Mode", I tried to disable it, but it still didn't help.
I recalled to have ran in the similar issue before, but forgot how to fix it. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Windows may have trouble with a bad UBD device entry in the Registry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-specific-registry-settings . You can delete all keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB (ans UISBSTOR, too), or use Nirsoft's USBDeview to delete some or all: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

If OP reinstalled Windows, faulty registry entries can’t be it. // Try with a live Linux, OP, just to see if it works. If it doesn’t, it’s likely hardware damage.

@DanielB But it worked with the display port. The rear one is recognized as USB-3.1(stable) and still supported 4K output. The left side is recognized as USB-2.0(unstable, sometimes it's not recognized) but also supported 1080P output. So it's physically working.

USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode uses an almost entirely separate set of pins on the USB-C connector. “Physically working” isn’t just binary yes/no. Also, while we’re at it: Flip the USB drive. While the connector is reversible, the damaged parts may only be in one orientation.

@DanielB I tried the both sides and it was not working, with multiple wires too. But the USB-A ports next to the USB-C ports are working... The chance that both USB-C ports physically broken the same way while the USB-A ports next to it were totally unaffected is low.

Looks like the PD/CC controller firmware in your laptop is corrupted. Try to update Lenovo "system firmware" from Lenovo website, UEFI BIOS plus EC, and be patient.
